# git tree is broken

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

How do I get my git tree to show correctly on a GUI git viewer?
My git tree in all GUI apps has no beginning and actually goes further below than the initial commit. I am the only one facing this problem in my company. I have no idea why but my git tree looks completely different than everyone else in my company.

I tried the following two apps to view the tree:

1. gitkraken
2. source tree

I with both apps I deleted all my repositories and cloned from a fresh directory.

Below are 2 image from the start and end of the git log in source tree

The first image shows my develop branch (the red one) is permanently stuck in a weird spot where I am not sure if I can push to that branch to master without history breaking.

The second image shows my branch (the red line) next to master (the blue line) going down into infinity with other branches.

This is not a problem with the repos as everyone else in the company has a nice branching tree when looking at a GUI. Where would I start to identify the problem with `git`?

[image: develop branch]

[image]

Comment: why the downvote? no comment?

Comment: It's because there are a number of unclear things with your question: (1) Are you referring to the blue branch when you say "_crazy broken tree_"? (2) What do you mean by "_looks completely different_"? What does _theirs_ look like? (3) What do you mean by "_permanently stuck in a weird spot_"? (4) Where did all the other "infinity" branches branch-out from? Basically, it's hard to understand what the issue is.

Comment: 1 the blue branch was my develop branch until it broke off. the broken tree I am talking about is the entire tree not just one branch
2 theirs looks like a normal looking git tree. The tree has a root and no branches that have no beginning, and all branches their branches break off of another branch. My git tree looks more like a git forest.

Comment: The graph is dynamically generated, not stored in git. Check the settings at the top of the history tab, most likely you are either looking at one branch instead of all, or looking at ancestor order instead of date order.

Comment: I checked that.The closest to fixing the problem is if I change the settings to show only the current branch, the problem is hidden. until I return to show all branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the true answer, I reformatted the computer and now it works great for reference here is what the tree should look like. Notice there are no line going into nothing.

[image]

Comment: That is technically an answer, and does work. I just wish there were some way to do this without reformatting the computer.