# Why git tree have multiple roots

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I am using the git source control for some project**s** (with more details : [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org) and [Atlasian SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/))
Everything is ok, but when I look at the root of the git tree of the project using the **[Date Order]**, I see the following

[image]

and when I change the order to the **[Ancestor Order]** I see the following

[image]

I really searched for the solution for this, and I could not find anything.
The only thing I found was this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45578612/) and its answer is not logical at all (suggesting formatting the computer)

Now my question is: I know that the git tree must have only one initial commit.
So what is the explanation for the first image (which use the **[Date Order]**), (which as I understand has a more than one Initial point)? Or do I misunderstand something?

Comment: A Git commit graph *can* have multiple roots, but yours probably does not. The Atlassian GUI is known to have at least one such bug in its graph-displaying code.

Comment: The graph is meaningful only when in "Ancestor order" and could be completely wrong when using other orders because dates could be changed when doing a rebase (which seems to be your case).

Comment: @Philippe There is no rebase at all in the whole project, any way thanks for the note

Comment: I hit the similar problem recently but I trace the extra lines in my case and found they don't have an end point. So I feel like a bug of sourcetree.